# Espresso AmbiguousViewMatcherException when trying to click a icon (TextView)

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

LinearLayout (productList) is dynamically populated with child views at runtime, as below:

```
@ViewById(R.id.ll_products)
LinearLayout productList;

public void createProductList() {
    productList.addView(getView(mobilePhone))
    productList.addView(getView(internet))
    productList.addView(getView(television))
}

public View getView(Product product) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    TextView layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_product, null);
    TextView productIcon = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tv_product_row_icon);
    productIcon.setText(product.getProductIcon());
    productName.setText(product.getName());
}
```

productList is deliberately LinearLayout, not ListView.

Product list has three products - each product has icon (duplications are possible).

I would like to record a scenario where I click on the icon a second product.
How do such a scenario avoiding AmbiguousViewMatcherException ?

Unfortunately, the following code will not work - three R.id.tv_product_row_icon will be found...

```
    ViewInteraction appCompatTextView = onView(withId(R.id.tv_product_row_icon));
    appCompatTextView.perform(scrollTo(), click());
```

How to specify that the second icon is to be clicked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you will have to create a custom [`Matcher`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/hamcrest/+/master/src/org/hamcrest/Matcher.java) for such case.

The following matches the `View` with specified index:

```
public static Matcher<View> withIndex(final Matcher<View> matcher, final int index) {
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        int currentIndex = 0;

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("with index: ");
            description.appendValue(index);
            matcher.describeTo(description);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
            return matcher.matches(view) && currentIndex++ == index;
        }
    };
}
```

Usage appropriate for your case:

```
Matcher<View> secondIconMatcher = allOf(withId(R.id.tv_product_row_icon));
onView(withIndex(secondIconMatcher , 1)).perform(click());
```

Comment: It works great! Thanks! 
However, I have a case where I have 5 icons - last icon is visible on the screen only after the scroll. When I use your solution I get an exception - NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with index: <4>.
Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: You answered your question by yourself - the view is not visible on screen. The solution is to match if the view is visible: `onView(matcher).check(matches(isDisplayed()));` inside try-catch block. If exception is thrown, then the parent view should be scrolled.